# How can I put a next & previous button inside my jumbotron?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm almost finished with my Full Stack Nanodegree final project and while I'm waiting for help on my instructor, I've decided to build my portfolio. However, I'm trying to add a next & previous button inside my jumbotron. It's not working. When I try to add those two buttons, it appears next to my placeholder image instead of the left and right of my container. How can I fix this? More specifically, I'm wondering where to place this snippet of code:

`<!-- Next and previous buttons -->
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>`

If you're interested in helping me, here's my GitHub repo: https://github.com/10asmock/portfolio.

I'm also using W3schools' guide on creating a JS slideshow as a reference: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Comment: are you using bootstrap 4?

Answer (score 0):

Float an element right or left by utilizing Bootstrap 4's `float-right` and `float-left` classes.

````
    <div class="float-left">
      <!-- left -->
    </div>
    <div class="float-right">
      <!-- right -->
    </div>```
````

More information can be found [in the Bootstrap v4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)